# Execute the same process N times and terminate it if it hasn't completed within X seconds

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have an external process, which takes some random time to run and at the end it prints some output in the standard output.

I need to write a python process which runs such external process N times; after X seconds, for each process which has terminated already it must collect the output, and for each process which hasn't terminated it must kill it.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in API:

http://strftime.org/ 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html

```
start_time = time.time()
# your code
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))
#'00:00:02'
```

To Kill the process, I don't know how you are processing this:

You can use:

```
import subprocess, signal 
p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
for line in out.splitlines():
   if 'iChat' in line:
   pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0])
   os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL) # -9 (equivalent.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html) module. A (quick and dirty) example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

count = 0
N = 10 # Change this per your requirement

def run_external_process():
    global count, scheduler

    # Execute the job N times
    count = count + 1

    if count == 10: # Shutdown the scheduler and exit
        scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)
        sys.exit(1)

    #Run your code here

# When each job is executed check for its output 
def listen_for_output():
   if event.retval: # Check the return value of your external process
       # Collect output
   else:
       # Call script to terminate process

try:
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler() # Initiate your scheduler
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('Failed to import module')
sys.exit(1)  

scheduler.add_job(run_external_process, 'interval', seconds=1, id='my_job_id')
# Add a listener to check the output of your external process
scheduler.add_listener(listen_for_output, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED|EVENT_JOB_ERROR) 
scheduler.start()
```